# How to find Intersections in a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list like this:

```
list={{a,b,c,d},{a,b,c,e,},{a,b,c,g},{a,b,c,x},{a,c,d}}
```

Now i want to use`Intersection`to find the same elements within the list so that the result is.

```
result={a,c}
```

Put differently: does `Intersection` only allow to compare single lists in that way `Intersection[{list1},{list2},{listx}]` or is there a trick to use Intersection like this `Intersection[list]` to obtain `result` ?

Comment: `Intersection @@ list` (look up `Apply`).

Comment: oh so easy thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
   Intersection[Sequence @@ list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thx ```Sequence```makes it even easier to understand...